# Check Store before API call NgRx Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am creating NgRx application but I am quite confused about its implementation as it is my first app with NgRx.
I have a store with **"Companies"** state. I gotta search the companies and return if found. 
If the required company is not found it should call the API and fetch the results likewise but the process is circular and runs infinite time.

Here is my code:

```
    this.companySearchCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(val => {
        if (val !== ' ' || val !== '') {
          this.store.select(getCompanys).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
//filter companies on the basis of search text
            const filteredData = data.filter(x =>
              x['name']
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(this.companySearchCtrl.value.toLowerCase())
            );
            console.log(filteredData);
            if (filteredData.length === 0) { //if data is not found in store
              console.log('got a call');
              this.store.dispatch(
                new CompanyActions.find({
                  where: { name: { regexp: `${val}/i` } } // call to API to search with regExp
                })
              );
            } else {
// if required data found in store
              console.log('got no call');
              this.filteredCompanies$ = of(filteredData);
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

This process runs fine if data is found in store. If data is not found in store or I dont get any results from API call it runs infinitely. 
How can I make this correct?

Answer (score 5):

Make a few conventions:

1. `state.Companies = null` is initial state if no request to server has been sent yet
2. `state.Companies = []` is state after first request was sent but no companies returned from server
3. use `createSelector` that filters your companies based on criteria you need
4. use `withLatestFrom` in your effects which will enable you to check store state within effects

Now, turn the logic the other way around:

1. when you look for companies, first fire an action that will trigger effects
2. in that effect, check if `state.Companies` is `null` or not
3. if its `null` > fire api request
4. if its not null > fire an action that will trigger selector for filtering
5. if data was not found even if `state.Companies` was not `null` that means either you need to refresh your `Companies` collection or the value doesn't exist on server

Comment: Actually I am using ngrx entity. So I think by default it does not allow to have null entities. What about using extra flag to check if the value exists in store or not?

Comment: yes, that would work also. and again, give that flag (mental) meaning so it can distinguish between cases entity not found in store and entity doesn't exist on server at all.

Answer (score 3):

Create another action named `dataNotFound`. If you found data then set its state `isFound` to true and if data does not find, set its state `isFound` to false and always before sending call with regex check `isFound` that either data was found in previous call or not. If data was not found then don't send call again.

I've made a little bit change in your code to manage this. You just have to create an action `dataNotFound` now.

```
     this.companySearchCtrl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            debounceTime(300),
            distinctUntilChanged()
          )
          .subscribe(val => {
            if (val !== ' ' || val !== '') {
              this.store.select(getCompanys).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
    //filter companies on the basis of search text
                const filteredData = data.filter(x =>
                  x['name']
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .startsWith(this.companySearchCtrl.value.toLowerCase())
                );
                console.log(filteredData);
                if (filteredData.length === 0) { //if data is not found in store
                  console.log('got a call');
                  this.store.select(isDataFound).subscribe(isFound => {
                      if(isFound) {
                          this.store.dispatch(
                          new CompanyActions.find({
                       where: { name: { regexp: `${val}/i` } } // call to API to 
                                                                search with regExp
                    })
                  );
                      } else {
                          this.store.dispatch(new CompanyActions.dataNotFound({isFound: false}));
                      } 
                  });

                } else {
    // if required data found in store
                  console.log('got no call');
                  this.store.dispatch(new CompanyActions.dataNotFound({isFound: true}));  
                  this.filteredCompanies$ = of(filteredData);
                }
              });
            }
          });
```